# Why are Shabbat candles lit 18 minutes before sunset?

Tags: shabbat, shiurim-measurements, candle-lighting

My understanding is that the number 18 is the amount of time it takes for an average person to walk 1 *mil* (side Q, how does this measurement translate to current English or metric units?)

Why was this measurement used, though?

Comment: Not all communities light Shabbat candles 18 minutes before sunset.

Comment: Many authorities believe it takes the average person 21.5 minutes to walk 1 _mil_.